# Source Control Explorer Cursor Icon Meaning Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

What is the meaning of this icon in Visual Studio 2013

[image: Icon Example]
[image]

I encountered it in the source control explorer.

Comment: And you're certain it's not the system-wide text pointer, right?

Comment: Can we have a bit more context as to where this appears?

Comment: It appears in source control explorer to the left of the folder icon.  It is definitely not system-wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that there is a pending rename on that object:

[image]